# .htaccess instead a range use 2 options

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this code in my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteRule    ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)?$    index.php?lang=$1&loc=$2    [NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/restaurants/?$    all_rest.php?lang=$1&loc=$2    [NC,L]
```

As you can see, the variables `lang` and `loc` can be anything in the range `([a-z]+)` but I dont need a total range I only need the words: `en` or `chin` for `lang` variable and `hk` or `kw` for `loc` variable.

I have tried with this:

```
RewriteRule    ^([en][chin])/([hk][kw])/restaurants/?$    all_rest.php?lang=$1&loc=$2    [NC,L]
```

But I dont know why only works for `hk kw` y no para `en chin`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using character sets, which would match individual characters. So, `[hk][kw]` would match these: `hk, hw, kk, kw`. You want this:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|chin)/(hk|kw)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&loc=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(en|chin)/(hk|kw)/restaurants/?$ all_rest.php?lang=$1&loc=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: perfect! is exactly what I was looking for